# ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'postFeedback' of undefined

Tags: angularjs, angular

**Version of Angular and Node** :

Angular CLI: 6.2.9
Node: 8.17.0

When I am clicking on Send Feedback button, its throwing error and stack-trace is below :-

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'postFeedback' of undefined
at FeedbackComponent.push../src/app/feedback/feedback.component.ts.FeedbackComponent.sendFeedback (feedback.component.ts:23)
at Object.eval [as handleEvent] (FeedbackComponent.html:5)
at handleEvent (core.js:10251)
at callWithDebugContext (core.js:11344)
at Object.debugHandleEvent [as handleEvent] (core.js:11047)
at dispatchEvent (core.js:7710)
at core.js:9190
at SafeSubscriber.schedulerFn [as _next] (core.js:3563)
```

feedback.component.html

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="offset-3"></div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <form name="form" #f="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="f.form.valid && sendFeedback()" novalidate class="feedback-form">
        <!-- Name -->
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="name">First Name</label>
          <input type="text"
                 id="name"
                 class="form-control"
                 name="name"
                 placeholder="Your name"
                 [(ngModel)]="model.name"
                 #name="ngModel"
                 [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': f.submitted && name.invalid }"
                 required/>
          <!-- input validation group -->
          <div *ngIf="f.submitted && name.invalid" class="invalid-input">
            <!-- individual validation errors -->
            <div *ngIf="name.errors?.required">Field is required</div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Email -->
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="email">Email</label>
          <input type="text"
                 id="email"
                 class="form-control"
                 name="email"
                 placeholder="Your email"
                 [(ngModel)]="model.email"
                 #email="ngModel"
                 [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': f.submitted && email.invalid }"
                 required email/>
          <!-- input validation group -->
          <div *ngIf="f.submitted && email.invalid" class="invalid-input">
            <!-- individual validation errors -->
            <div *ngIf="email.errors?.required">Field is required</div>
            <div *ngIf="email.errors?.email">Field is not a valid email</div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Feedback -->
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="feedback">Feedback</label>
          <textarea
            id="feedback"
            class="form-control"
            name="feedback"
            placeholder="Your feedback"
            rows="10"
            [(ngModel)]="model.feedback"
            #feedback="ngModel"
            [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': f.submitted && feedback.invalid }"
            required minlength="10">
       </textarea>
          <!-- input validation group -->
          <div *ngIf="f.submitted && feedback.invalid" class="invalid-input">
            <!-- individual validation errors -->
            <div *ngIf="feedback.errors?.required">Field is required</div>
            <div *ngIf="feedback.errors?.minlength">Field is too small (try 10 characters)</div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info pull-right">
          <i class="fa fa-envelope-o"></i>
          <span> Send Feedback</span>
        </button>
      </form>
    </div>
    <div class="offset-3"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

feedback.component.ts

```ts
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';
import {ApiService} from '../shared/api.service';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-feedback',
  templateUrl: './feedback.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./feedback.component.css']
})
export class FeedbackComponent implements OnInit {
  model: FeedbackViewModel = {
    name: '',
    email: '',
    feedback: ''
  };

  constructor(public apiService: ApiService) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  sendFeedback(): void {
    this.apiService.postFeedback(this.model).subscribe(
      res => {
        location.reload();
      },
      err => {
        alert('An error has occurred while sending feedback');
      }
    );
  }

}

export interface FeedbackViewModel {
  name: string;
  email: string;
  feedback: string;
}
```

Service
api.service.ts

```js
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs';
import {FeedbackViewModel} from '../feedback/feedback.component';


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ApiService {
  private BASE_URL = window['cfgApiBaseUrl'] + '/api';
  public ALL_NOTEBOOKS_URL = `${this.BASE_URL}/notebooks/all`;
  private SEND_FEEDBACK_URL = `${this.BASE_URL}/feedback`;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {

  }

  getAllNotebooks(): Observable<Notebook[]> {
    return this.http.get<Notebook[]>(this.ALL_NOTEBOOKS_URL);
  }

  postFeedback(feedback: FeedbackViewModel): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.post(this.SEND_FEEDBACK_URL, feedback);
  }

  postNotebook(notebook: Notebook): Observable<Notebook> {
    return this.http.post<Notebook>(this.SAVE_UPDATE_NOTEBOOK, notebook);
  }

  deleteNotebook(id: string): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.delete(this.DELETE_NOTEBOOK_URL + id);
  }

  getAllNotes(): Observable<Note[]> {
    return this.http.get<Note[]>(this.ALL_NOTES_URL);
  }

  getNotesByNotebook(notebookId: string): Observable<Note[]> {
    return this.http.get<Note[]>(this.NOTES_BY_NOTEBOOK_URL + notebookId);
  }

  saveNote(note: Note): Observable<Note> {
    return this.http.post<Note>(this.SAVE_UPDATE_NOTE_URL, note);
  }

  deleteNote(noteId: string): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.delete(this.DELETE_NOTE_URL + noteId);
  }
}
```

I have tried to resolve it by changing form to 'register-form', but it always shows same TypeError.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That Angular error log seems to indicate the service injected is 'undefined'.
My guess is your service isn't defined in a provider at the point in time which you are calling it's method, but I'd expect more DI based errors if that were the case. Is this in a provider array of a specific component or module that isn't loaded at the time you call it?

just a guess, best of luck,
Happy coding!

Comment: Thanks! Just checked it HttpModule was not getting loaded. In app.module.ts imported HttpModule again and it's working good now.